# passing variable to function

Tags: arduino-ide

I have the following code to turn on or off led. I would like to modify the function to pass the pin as well. what should X be substituted with?

```
#define BIN_LED 2
#define PIN_LED 3

void led(uint8_t x, bool on) {
 digitalWrite(x, on ? LOW : HIGH);
}

void setup() {}

void loop() {
 led(BIN_LED, true);
 delay(1000);
 led(BIN_LED, false);
 delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: think ..... what is X in `digitalWrite(X, on)`?

Comment: FWIW, consider *why* you're doing this as well. If you want a shorter function name, consider just aliasing the fn. If you want a more "meaningful" fn, I'm not sure this achieves that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've done it. All that's left is to specify a data-type 'X' in the function declaration, just as you've already done for 'on'. 'uint8_t' would be a reasonable choice.

Comment: it didn't work. I updated the question with your suggestion.

Comment: @motionchannel  It did not work because you have not configured the pin as an output. The answer is correct, the code compiles and correctly passes the pin number. Put `pinMode (BIN_LED, OUTPUT);` in your `setup()` function to make your code light an LED. You could look at some example code from the Arduino IDE to see how this works.